# How to change URL from CI/CD in Gitlab on Automation Testing using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, cicd

I have 3 env (dev/test/prod) and I want to change the URL from the gitlab-ci.yml so I can choose from CI/CD which env I want to run the tests.
Currently I run:

```
- robot -v BROWSER:Chrome -d results/Chrome test/test.robot
```

I can't find any info on this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass URL though command line, try below solution

```
- robot -v url:http://your_url -v BROWSER:Chrome -d results/Chrome test/test.robot
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the issue is that I had already had the URL hardcoded, and if I remove it, it doesn't work.

Go To    https://test.com

How can I make it to take URL from the command line?

Comment: are you using git pipelines to trigger execution?

Comment: I solved it thanks. My global var was not named url and because of this, I couldn't overwrite it with -v url:https://. Thanks again

Comment: okay. Great, Good luck!